# How to post array data from a form to mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, checkbox

please forgive naivety and innocence...I am not a programmer! I have spent the best part of 4 days on this and I am ready for a PHP lesson or intense therapy.

Scenario: DB built in mySQL. Table with all columns varchar(50) except ID and age - both INT. See below, I just need a 'Yes' value in the checkbox linked colums/fields.

I want to insert data with a form that has both textboxes and checkboxes. I thought best way to do this was php array...??

Form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Childname
  <input type="text" name="textfield[childname]" />
  </label>
  <p>
    <label>Age
    <input type="text" name="textfield[age]" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Parent Name
    <input type="text" name="textfield[parent_name]" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Contact Number
    <input type="text" name="textfield[contact_no]" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Subjects<br />
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[scratch]" value="checkbox" />
    Scratch</label> 
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[app_inventor]" value="checkbox" />
    App Inventor</label>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[html]" value="checkbox" />
    HTML</label>
  </p>
  <p>Sessions Attended<br />
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[nov12]" value="checkbox" />
    Nov 2012</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[dec12]" value="checkbox" />
    Dec 2012</label>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$childrecord = array("childname","age","parent_name","contact_no","scratch","app_inventor","html");

if(isset($_POST['childrecord'])){
    $childrecord = $_POST['childrecord'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($childrecord as $key => $value); {
    $i++;

    $sql="INSERT INTO tblchildren (childrecord) VALUES ($_POST['childrecord'])";
mysql_query($sql);

}

?>
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance....

Comment: What is your question/your problem?

Comment: Obviously the PHP is not working. I have only learned a small amount and didn't know this forum was 'owned' by programmers (@Rajeev).

Comment: I've tried to use isset for the checkboxes but I get undefined index on the ones that aren't checked in the form, so I thought array, but I have the array syntax all wrong I think....

Comment: @user2550346 this site is not owned by programmers but moderated by programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store your form data in your code.

For this you have to make following changes in your code and database.

## In Form

```
note: Input field value should be relevant.

With your existing html code your process.php will get data in this structure


        Array
        (
            [textfield] => Array
                (
                    [childname] => dang
                    [age] => 18
                    [parent_name] => doctor
                    [contact_no] => 100
                )

            [checkbox] => Array
                (
                    [scratch] => checkbox
                    [app_inventor] => checkbox
                    [html] => checkbox
                    [nov12] => checkbox
                    [dec12] => checkbox
                )

            [Submit] => Submit
        )
```

So you need to modify your process.php

Before that you have to modify structure of your table, follow these steps

```
1. Delete your existing table
2. Create new table




 DROP TABLE tblchildren ;


         CREATE TABLE tblchildren
         (
           id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
           childname VARCHAR(30),
           age TINYINT,
           parent_name VARCHAR(30),
          contact_no VARCHAR(20),
           scratch ENUM('yes','no'),
           app_inventor ENUM('yes','no'),
           html ENUM('yes','no'),
           sesNov12Attnd ENUM('yes','no'),
           sesDec12Attnd ENUM('yes','no')
         );
```

Since you are new to php so i have used basic function,
I will suggest you to use switch from **mysql to mysqli**

## process.php

```
        <?php

            $con=mysql_connect("hostname","username","pass");
            $db=mysql_select_db('dbname', $con);

            //check form is submitted    
            if(isset($_POST)){

            //mysql_real_escape_string() prevents from sql injection.
            $childname= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textfield']['childname']);
            $age=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textfield']['age']);
            $parentName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textfield']['parent_name']);
            $contactNo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textfield']['contact_no']);


            $scratch=isset($_POST['checkbox']['scratch'])?'yes':'no';
            $appInventor=isset($_POST['checkbox']['app_inventor'])?'yes':'no';
            $html=isset($_POST['checkbox']['html'])?'yes':'no';
            $nov12=isset($_POST['checkbox']['nov12'])?'yes':'no';
            $dec12=isset($_POST['checkbox']['dec12'])?'yes':'no';

            $sql="INSERT INTO tblchildren(childname, age, parent_name, contact_no, scratch,app_inventor,html, sesNov12Attnd, sesDec12Attnd )
            VALUES
            ('$childname',$age,'$parentName','$contactNo','$scratch','$appInventor','$html','$nov12','$dec12')";

            mysql_query($sql);
            }else{
                echo "Form Not SUbmitted";
             }
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much - got so far and on submisison of form got this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,no,no,yes,no,no)' at line 2. I'm running XAMPP with MySQL version 5.5.27...

Comment: You need to modify query as :-

  $sql="INSERT INTO tblchildren(childname, age, parent_name, contact_no, scratch,app_inventor,html, sesNov12Attnd, sesDec12Attnd )
            VALUES
            ('$childname',$age,'$parentName','$contactNo','$scratch','$appInventor','$html','$nov12','$dec12')";

Comment: why would you use enum? use a bit(1) or a tinyint(1)

Comment: Please let me know if there is any other problem .

Comment: @mc_fish , enum has better performance.  

for more details check :- [link](http://techhelplist.com/index.php/tech-tutorials/42-databases/65-mysql-performance-bit-vs-tinyint-vs-enum)

Comment: yeah but they bring a bunch of problems with them on a programming level

Comment: With tinyint or bit create problem i certain circumstances.

like if you search for null values then all value with 0 is returned.
but this is not case with enum.

Comment: @user2539459 - That worked a treat and thank you so much. You've saved me much time and stress!